# Direct boot from Windows to Linux with UEFI

Tags: linux, windows, uefi, bcdedit

I'm trying to create scripts on both Linux and Windows allowing direct booting to each other with UEFI.

On linux it looks like:

```
efibootmgr -n 0001 && sync && reboot
```

Where "0001" is for Boot0001 - Windows UEFI bootentry. And ["efibootmgr -n"](https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr) sets specified entry to be booted with the first order for the one time.

Is there any way to set the one-time boot order from Windows? Tried using bcdedit, but it cannot modify UEFI settings. Also tried to run efibootmgr from Linux Subsystem, but it (expectedly) wasn't successful.

P.S.: I hate using GRUB on modern machines, only UEFI (maybe with refind).

Comment: `bcdedit` *can* alter the EFI boot variables, but I'm not enough of an expert on it to be able to tell you how to reliably do what you want with it. The [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool can also edit EFI boot variables, but it's a GUI tool, so unless you have a way to script it, it won't do what you want. Given the existence of EasyUEFI, there must be a way to do it in a program, but I don't know the relevant Windows APIs.

Comment: @RodSmith [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/7akp7n/question_direct_boot_from_windows_to_linux_with/) I've discribed my issues with bcdedit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bcdedit.exe /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence {target_GUID} /addfirst
```

Works great for this

Comment: Downvoting without arguments :(